# Will Azure AppServices bill for every database transaction and resources usage or my monthly bill from Azure calculator will cover the bill

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-app-service-plans, azure-billing

My company is about to deploy a .net core 5 app on Azure AppServices. The app uses Azure SQL database with a lot of read and write. Whenever user open the app dashboard, a lot of query is sent to the SQL database to generate dashboard data.
As we will be using pay as you go model, would Azure bill us for every transaction on CPU, database query or the amount Azure calculator generated will cover our monthly bill irrespective of our app resources usage?.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Azure SQL Database and Azure App Services, both belongs to Platform-as-a-Service (PaaS).**

The Pricing/Billing Model is different on the above each service.

**Azure SQL Database:**
Mainly there are two pricing models which can be used to pay for Azure SQL - DTU and vCores.

- DTU is a way of measuring compute resources required to run your SQL database.
- vCores are a way of measuring the resource specs in a way i.e., compatible to on-premises server cores.

**vCore pricing model provides greater flexibility than the DTU model.**

- Azure SQL Service has a complex model around 18 possible combinations of deployment models, service tiers and compute models.
- When evaluating vCore pricing, there are 2 options - provisioned compute and serverless compute.
- Also Pricing varies between Deployment Models, Service Tiers you choose to deploy the SQL Servers.

**Azure App Service:** Pricing depends on the various factors like OS, Service Tiers, SSL Connections, Support, etc.

**References:**

1. [Azure App Service, SQL Database Pricing Calculator and its example scenarios of how the Billing happens](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/)
2. [Simplified Azure SQL Pricing](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/azure-cvo-blg-azure-sql-pricing-simplified)